# How can we use sqlc with pgx (postgres) for dealing with transactions?

Tags: go, pgx, sqlc

I'm new to sqlc and i want to integrate transactions in my microservice.

Should i pass a pool & queries at the same time ?

my repository defines only queries

```
type OrgRepository struct {
    queries *query.Queries
}
```

```
// versions:
//   sqlc v1.25.0

package query

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgconn"
)

type DBTX interface {
    Exec(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) (pgconn.CommandTag, error)
    Query(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) (pgx.Rows, error)
    QueryRow(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) pgx.Row
}

func New(db DBTX) *Queries {
    return &Queries{db: db}
}

type Queries struct {
    db DBTX
}

func (q *Queries) WithTx(tx pgx.Tx) *Queries {
    return &Queries{
        db: tx,
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you can, and [that is what the example code does](https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/latest/howto/transactions.html). One alternative would be to add the `*pgxpool.Pool` into `OrgRepository` (but I'm not really sure how your code is structured).  You might find the [`emit_methods_with_db_argument` option](https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/latest/reference/config.html#go) of use (the [PR](https://github.com/sqlc-dev/sqlc/pull/1279) explains the rationale).

Comment: That's the point, i don't know if putting *pgxpool.Pool with queries in the repository struct is a good idea. It's redondant in my opinion. Thanks so much for the comment, i'll try to use the emit_methods_with_db_argument. Thanks a lot

Comment: "is a good idea"; unfortunately that's going to be somewhat [subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and depend on your use-case. For example [this](https://github.com/sqlc-dev/sqlc/issues/383#issuecomment-1213540025) approach might work, but could also create issues (mocking is mentioned, but also, what happens if `WithTx` is called when you are already within a transaction). Personally I don't have an issue with passing the `*pgxpool.Pool` because it makes your intention clear.